# Avoid caching public NPM packages to private nexus repository during build

Tags: angular, npm, package.json, nexus3

I have an Angular project where I use some private libs and many public libs in my package.json.
After couple of months since I update the package.json and update versions of almost all packages, I have this problem where all the older versions of libs are in the nexus repo. I know there is this package management in nexus repo. Other than that is there any option to cache/publish selected packages to nexus repo?
Any help is appreciated.

I tried freeing the space using `df -h` and deleting all journal files from the Ubuntu system. Didn't help anymore.